# What does 889271 represent in the blockchain index leveldb databases?

Tags: blockchain

I am opening up the blockchain index databases with leveldb, and I am seeing a repeating number, 889271, at the start of every value entry...

I am attempting to decipher the following key value pair

```
'b'e2bf047e7e5a191aa4ef34d314979dc9986e0f19251edaba5940fd1fe365a712 = 889271000b010008010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d9ced4ed1130f7b7faad9be25323ffafa33232a17c3edf6cfd97bee6bafbdd97b9aa8e4ef0ff0f1ecd513f7c
```

Using

```
https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#block-headers
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoin_Core_0.11_(ch_2):_Data_Storage
```

I believe i have everything deciphered properly, except for 889271

Any chance someone can confirm what 889271 represents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are thinking of 889271 as a decimal number; it is not. It is a hexadecimal value that just happens to be composed of numeric digits.

That is the [Variable Sized Integer serialization](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/serialize.h#L276) of the version number of the Bitcoin Core client that created that database entry.